# While installing npm package from github getting error with message "is not valid repository name"

Tags: github, npm

I wanted to install [react-scheduler](https://github.com/Bitnoise/react-scheduler) npm package to my react.ts project.

I runed next command: `D:\University\Degree project\TestingSchedule1\my-app>npm install '@bitnoi.se/react-scheduler'`

And got next error:

```
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/bitnoi.se/react-scheduler'.git
npm ERR! fatal: remote error:
npm ERR!   is not a valid repository name
npm ERR! Visit https://support.github.com/ for help

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\koten\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-10T09_02_58_820Z-debug-0.log
```

Chat gpt said it can be problrm with SSH Key when I'm trying to install my private package, but this is not mine repository and this is public/